# Getting Error in Filtering Data

Tags: php

I am new here i am facing problem to filtering data without showing it on page.
i am getting the error please help me. sorry for bad English.

**Error:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: search_result in
>   /storage/ssd3/688/2645688/public_html/test.php on line
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /storage/ssd3/688/2645688/public_html/test.php on line

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['search'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `username`, `password`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    
}

function filterTable($query)
{

$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cable");
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>
<form action="test.php" method="POST"> 
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        <br><br><div class="search">
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="64" placeholder="Search" />
 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Search</button>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</br></br>
</form>

<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id<br></th>
                    <th>Username:</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                   </tr>
                                          <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?><br></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['password'];?></td>
                    
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
```

Comment: put the function on the top. kindly add $connect in your filterTable($connect,$query);

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because when page loads `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`is false therefore `$search_result = filterTable($query);` doesn't executes and thus `mysqli_fetch_array` gets `NULL`.

The solution is simple, we have to keep it in mind that at page loads there may be no `$search_result`

```
<?php
$search_result = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['search'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `username`, `password`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cable");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>
<form action="test.php" method="POST"> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <br><br><div class="search">
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="64" placeholder="Search" />
 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Search</button>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
</br></br>
</form>

<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id<br></th>
                    <th>Username:</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                   </tr>
                                          <?php if(!empty($search_result)): while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?><br></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['password'];?></td>

                </tr>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: this guy is right. when you load the page it will give you error.$search_result will go NULL / undefined.